# Updating usernames and passwords for 450 WordPress databases - 450 ftp Accounts and 450 MySQL user

Tags: mysql, ftp, scripting, automated

How would you update these in a consistent, reliable manner? I'm new enough to system administration, self taught and still learning but - I have this problem to solve in no specific time and under my own initiative as I work in a company where I'm the only sys admin.

I've noticed that our password policy isn't exactly foolproof in that if you have 1 wordpress password the ftp account for that user and the mysql account for that site, then you can quickly gain access to 90% of our portfolio.

I'd like to change this.
I have 3 virtual servers with about 170/170/110 WordPress installations between the three. Each has it's own FTP user and MySQL database.
What would you do?

Comment: Are all the users that log in working for your company? how many need to log in daily? I ask because although there are several possible ways of doing this technically, the main issue is the 'political' one regarding the users. For example you can create a script to reset every password with a random one and tell the users to contact you to get the new password.

Answer (score 0):

I would centralize that information in a directory.

The three services you mention support authentication using LDAP:

- There are [several plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=ldap) to integrate WordPress with LDAP.
- The Enterprise version of MySQL can perform [PAM authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html), indirectly providing LDAP integration.
- You don't mention what FTP server are you using, but it is highly probable that there's a way to use LDAP/AD to authenticate your users, too. See, for example, [ProFTPd](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_ldap.html).

With regards to password policies (quality, expiration, ...), they can be enforce [directly in the directory](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10). this is the case for [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.3-Release&format=html), [Apache DS](https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/4.3-password-policy.html) and [389](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Password_Syntax).